# How to display a term of taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms

My doubt is how can I show a "term” of an specific taxonomy, the problem is that I have not found an applying example, just short code lines that don’t show me nothing at all.

I want please the entire code to show the post.

My post type names: “sección_deportes"
My taxonomy names: “tipo_deporte”
and the term I want to show: “futbol”

I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512137/how-to-sort-post-by-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress?s=f36f5472-cf86-4e93-8ee2-5856d4ef06bf

but the loop shows me the same posts repeatedly.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to display a custom post belonging to a category of a taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to answer this question:
[Specify number of posts in my 'tax_query'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137879/specify-number-of-posts-in-my-tax-query)

I wanted to show the posts for 'futbol' within the 'tipo_deporte' taxonomy:

```
        <?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tipo_deporte',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('futbol'),
                     )
            )
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

   if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

     //The Post

        }
    }
    ?>
```