# Specify number of posts in my 'tax_query'

Tags: posts, tax-query

I'm showing posts of the term 'football' belonging to the taxonomy 'section', and everything works perfectly but 
Where can I specify the number of posts I want to show?

just like this: 'showposts' => 3

I do not know where to put it

```
    $myquery['tax_query'] = array(
                   array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'section',
                        'terms' => array('futbol'),
                        'field' => 'slug',
                    ),
        );
        query_posts($myquery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never user `query_posts`, under any circumstances. Use `WP_Query` instead, which is how query_posts works internally, but without the trickery and downsides.

You'll also find that the WP_Query documentation gives you explanations for every parameter, including what you are trying to do:

> **posts_per_page (int)** - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced `showposts` parameter). Use
>   `'posts_per_page'=>-1` to show all posts (the '`offset`' parameter is
>   ignored with a `-1` value). Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is
>   off after using this parameter. Note: if the query is in a feed,
>   wordpress overwrites this parameter with the stored '`posts_per_rss`'
>   option. To reimpose the limit, try using the '`post_limits`' filter, or
>   filter '`pre_option_posts_per_rss`' and return -1

Including an example:

> ### Show x Posts per page
>
> Display 3 posts per page:
>
> ```
> $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' );
> ```

or as i would put it:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display the post
    }
}
```

Notice how the main loop is the same as when using query_posts, only I've added `$query->` to the beginning of `have_posts` and `the_post`?

You can now modify the parameters to add in your tax query

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        ...etc
    )
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: If it works you can mark it as the correct answer by accepting it, it's the tick under the votes

Comment: Never? Seriously? I think so long as you know what you're doing it can be pretty useful, like template parts that use "the loop" (though in this case `WP_Query` is certainly the way to go).

Comment: ***Never***, a scythe could be used as an effective surgical tool, I don't see good surgeons using it. If you're in that situation then your template needs a separate part for the loop, and inside the loop, separation of concerns

Answer (score 0):

You want `posts_per_page` instead:

```
$myquery = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'section',
            'terms' => array( 'futbol' ),
            'field' => 'slug',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks :)
but, Is there any way to do with the code I put? 
because I tried your code and not only showed posts of 'futbol', also showed the other sports :s

Answer (score 0):

This works, thanks Tom :)

```
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'section',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array('futbol'),
                         )
                )
            );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

       if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();

         //The Post

            }
        }
        ?>
```